# Is there an easier way to set/get values in a gSOAP request/response?

Tags: gsoap, onvif

I am using gSOAP to configure an ONVIF compatible camera.
Currently, I am manually setting all the parameters in the request by doing something like this. This is for the **SetVideEncoderConfiguration**

```
MediaBindingProxy mediaDevice (uri);
AUTHENTICATE (mediaDevice);
_trt__SetVideoEncoderConfiguration req;
_trt__SetVideoEncoderConfigurationResponse resp;
struct tt__VideoEncoderConfiguration encoderConfig;
struct tt__VideoResolution resolutionConfig;
encoderConfig.Name = strdup (name);
encoderConfig.UseCount = 1;
encoderConfig.Quality = 50;

if (strcmp (encoding, "H264") == 0)
encoderConfig.Encoding = tt__VideoEncoding__H264;
else if (strcmp (encoding, "JPEG") == 0)
encoderConfig.Encoding = tt__VideoEncoding__JPEG;

encoderConfig.token = strdup (profileToken);
encoderConfig.SessionTimeout = (LONG64)"PT0S";
resolutionConfig.Width=1280;
resolutionConfig.Height=720;
encoderConfig.Resolution = &resolutionConfig;
tt__VideoRateControl rateControl;
rateControl.FrameRateLimit = 15;
rateControl.EncodingInterval = 1;
rateControl.BitrateLimit = 4500;
encoderConfig.RateControl = &rateControl;
struct tt__H264Configuration h264;
h264.GovLength = 30;
h264.H264Profile = tt__H264Profile__Baseline;
encoderConfig.H264 = &h264;

struct tt__MulticastConfiguration multicast;
struct tt__IPAddress address;
address.IPv4Address = strdup ("0.0.0.0");
multicast.Address = &address;

encoderConfig.Multicast = &multicast;

req.Configuration = &encoderConfig;
req.ForcePersistence = true;



int ret = mediaDevice.SetVideoEncoderConfiguration (&req, resp);
qDebug () << "Set Encoder: " << ret;
```

Is there an easier way to do this? May be some function calls that set the request parameters? Another way I found with **GetMediaUri** was to use something like

```
soap_new_req__trt__GetStreamUri (mediaDevice.soap,soap_new_req_tt__StreamSetup (mediaDevice.soap, (enum tt__StreamType)0, soap_new_tt__Transport(mediaDevice.soap), 1, NULL), "profile1");
```

Are these the only two ways for client side code with gSOAP?

-Mandar Joshi

Comment: Take care about memory leaks, you should use `soap_malloc` to allocate string and not `strdup`.

Answer (score 4):

There are four variations of `soap_new_T()` to allocate data of type `T` in C++ with gSOAP:

- `T * soap_new_T(struct soap*)` returns a new instance of `T` that is default
  initialized and allocated on the heap managed by the `soap` context.
- `T * soap_new_T(struct soap*, int n)` returns an array of `n` new instances of
  `T` on the managed heap.  The instances in the array are default initialized as described above.
- `T * soap_new_req_T(struct soap*, ...)` (structs and classes only) returns a
  new instance of `T` allocated on the managed heap and sets the required data members to the values specified in the other arguments `...`.
- `T * soap_new_set_T(struct soap*, ...)` (structs and classes only) returns a
  new instance of `T` on the managed heap and sets the public/serializable data members to the values specified in the other arguments `...`.

Use `soap_strdup(struct soap*, const char*)` instead of `strdup` to dup strings onto the managed heap.

All data on the managed heap is mass-deleted with `soap_destroy(soap)` and
`soap_end(soap)` (call these in that order) which must be called before `soap_done(soap)` or `soap_free(soap)`.

To allocate pointers to data, use templates:

```
template<class T>
T * soap_make(struct soap *soap, T val)
{
  T *p = (T*)soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(T));
  if (p)
    *p = val;
  return p;
}
template<class T>
T **soap_make_array(struct soap *soap, T* array, int n)
{ 
  T **p = (T**)soap_malloc(soap, n * sizeof(T*));
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    p[i] = &array[i];
  return p;
}
```

Then use `soap_make<int>(soap, 123)` to create a pointer to the value `123` on the managed heap and `soap_make_array(soap, soap_new_CLASSNAME(soap, 100), 100)` to create 100 pointers to 100 instances of `CLASSNAME`.

The gSOAP tools also generate deep copy operations for you: `CLASSNAME::soap_dup(struct soap*)` creates a deep copy of the object and allocates it in a another `soap` context that you provide as argument. Use `NULL` as this argument to allocate unmanaged deep copies (but these cannot have pointer cycles!). Then delete unmanaged copies with `CLASSNAME::soap_del()` for deep deletion of all members and then `delete` the object itself.

See [Memory management in C++](https://www.genivia.com/doc/databinding/html/index.html#memory2) for more details. Use gSOAP 2.8.39 and greater.